# Using the parse backend to populate a UI in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, parse-platform

I am trying to pull data from my parse database backend service and populate fields into a UI (Using the latest version of Xcode and Parse framework). I have successfully done so with a table view using 'PFQueryTableViewController' and creating queries which draw some of the information I would like to have using the following code:

```
PFFile *thumbnail = [object objectForKey:@"profilePic"];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @""];
cell.imageView.file = thumbnail;
cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"firstName"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Points: %@", [object objectForKey:@"points"]];
```

When I import the png containers and templates I am struggling to pull the data into the desired locations. I would like to have a single template in the app populated by the data of the user thats logged in (Login system already functioning correctly). Could anyone give me an example of how I could query let's say the PFFile @"ProfilePic" into a specific area of the UI? Am I correct to be using the Parse Framework or should I reconsider?. Constructive answers really appreciated... Happy coding!

Comment: What is the issue you encountered?

Comment: I can only seem to be able to pull data into specific UIController windows such as table view but not to a blank UI template (a custom UI view). Not sure if i am just not meant to be using the parse framework for that specific task?

Comment: I am relatively new to parse and it seems very efficient as a web end so I may be overlooking something